# Postgresql Docker role does not exist

Tags: database, postgresql, docker

I downloaded the docker container for postgres: https://hub.docker.com/r/library/postgres/, and did the following:

```
$ docker run --name satgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword -d -p 5432:5432 postgres
satgres | "docker-entrypoint.s…" | 5 seconds ago | Up 6 seconds | 0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp | satgres
$ docker exec -it c8f1b22cc41e /bin/bash        
# psql -U postgres
psql (10.1)
postgres=# CREATE DATABASE mytest;
postgres=# \password postgres
postgres=# CREATE ROLE ming WITH LOGIN PASSWORD 'pass1234';
postgres=# ALTER ROLE ming CREATEDB;
postgres=# CREATE DATABASE sjk;
postgres=# GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE youtube TO ming;
postgres=# \connect sjk
youtube=# ALTER ROLE ming lOGIN;
```

My plan is to use this database on docker with Django, so first want to check I can connect, but I cant.

```
$ psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres
$ psql: FATAL:  role "postgres" does not exist
$ psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U ming
$ psql: FATAL:  role "ming" does not exist
```

I do the same with PSequal.app, says the same thing,
Im running on Mac High Sierra.

Why am I getting this error? The role exists, or at least it seems it to me...

Comment: The only Solution is here https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/issues/756#issuecomment-979818733

Answer (score 141, accepted):

The problem was simple enough that my computer was already running an instance of Postgres that I was not aware was still running (not inside Docker) on `:5432`, checked with:

```
$ lsof -n -i:5432 | grep LISTEN
```

So I remembered I installed it via https://gist.github.com/sgnl/609557ebacd3378f3b72, I ran

```
$ pg-stop
```

And then I had no problem connecting to the Docker instance.

## Edit (2019/07/02)

This question recently passed 10,000 views, so I thought I should elaborate more on why this happened.

Usually running through docker, using python and connecting to a postgres database requires you to install `psycopg2`, via `pip3 install psycopg2`, but if you run this command you will get:

```sh
Error: pg_config executable not found.
```

This is because psycopg2 requires an operating system install of the postgres libraries:

```sh
yum install postgresql-devel
apt-get install postgresql-client
```

Now, on a Mac, you will need to do the same with brew:

```sh
brew install postgresql
```

One thing that I didn't realise, is that on Mac, doing the above will not only install required libraries, but **also** start a database on `:5432`. Because this was all done in the background, it didn't occur to me that this was the problem as none of the usual errors popped up to inform that the port was being used, etc...

Comment: Same happened with me. Your answer saved my day :) Thanks. (For future users, if you are in mac and installed postgres using brew then to stop it just use `brew services stop postgresql` and you will be able to connect to the docker postgres instance)

Comment: I was on my MAC so I had to do: brew services stop postgresql

Comment: I had the same issue, and decided to make a function in my `~/.bash_profile` to check whats running on a port:  `checkaport(){ lsof -n -i:$1 }`.  Then you can use it like `checkaport 5432` after doing `source ~/.bash_profile`.

Comment: lost hours with this issue - I was on Mac with a local postgres running and tried to connect to one inside Docker

Comment: Thanks this reminded me about the local the service `brew services stop postgresql` or `brew services stop postgresql@<version>`

Comment: Really surprising that nowhere mentions that installing postgres using brew actually starts a database on port 5432 in the background! No wonder I could never use port 5432 to connect to the docker instance.

Answer (score 32):

In my case, the problem may be due also to the use of a super user who is not postgres. Lhe developers chose the user georchestra in the geOrchestra docker composition.
Extract from the dockerfile:

```
environment:
  - POSTGRES_USER=georchestra

HEALTHCHECK --interval=30s --timeout=30s \
  CMD pg_isready -U $POSTGRES_USER
```

consequently, you will have to use the option "-U georchestra" to connect to the container.

```
$ docker exec -it docker_database_1 psql -U georchestra
psql (10.5 (Debian 10.5-1.pgdg90+1))
Type "help" for help.
```

and of course, trying to connect with the user postgres causes an error:

```
docker exec -it docker_database_1 psql -U postgres
psql: FATAL:  role "postgres" does not exist
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, the problem was just that I didn't have a superuser called postgres.

Answer (score 17):

If you're using docker-compose, add a user called `postgres` in your docker-compose.yml like so:

```yaml
environment:
  - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
    (...rest of variables)
```

**CAUTION:** Executing the following command will result in the removal of all volumes, leading to the loss of all data in your database

Finally, restart your container(s) while deleting the volumes:

```
docker-compose down --volumes && docker-compose up
```

Comment: To someone who see it, make sure you're understand that all your volumes will be deleted.

Comment: This is a little strange advice to delete all your volumes with the command above. To create a new storage for postgres from scratch, you need either delete postgres volume if it is named volume (`docker volume ls` for finding right volume to delete), or delete folder with postgres data if it is bind volume.